# How to restrict cognito authenticated users to attach iot policy to cognito identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I want to subscribe a Iot shadow using cognito credentials. For this I have to attach policy to the authenticated cognito identity. Means After user logs in user will get the identity id. Then I'm attaching a previously created iot policy to that identity. The policy im attaching has the access to connect and subscribe device shadow.
Method I'm using for this 'AttachPrinciplePolicy' / 'AttachPolicy'.
Both of these method takes two parameter, 1. policy name, 2. Identity id to which i want to attach.
Here the problem is regarding security. Because once user authenticated then the user can attach any policy by just specifying the policy name. A hacker can use some techniques to change the policy name in code then it might cause a major vulnerability.

I want to restrict the user in a way that the cognito authenticated user can attach only the particular policy which has the access to connect and subscribe a shadow.

Can it be done using some IAM roles/policy ? So that the user can attach only the specific policy ?

Please suggest.

I have tried using IAM policy but when Im specifying a particular policy arn to the AttachPrinciplePolicy action's resource it is not working.
IAM policy which i have used is below

```
{
  "Action": [
     "iot:AttachPolicy",
     "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy"
   ],
   "Resource": [
       "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:policy/AccessByCognito_Policy"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Can it be done using some IAM roles/policy ? So that the user can attach only the specific policy ?
Or any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [AWS IoT Custom Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth.html) instead. You can attach policies on the go with a lambda function.

You can send aws cognito id token when connecting to aws iot.

In the lambda function you can verify the JWT id token and return the IAM policy as json. You can also determine how long that policy will be attached to the session.

```
{
 "isAuthenticated":true,
 "principalId": "xxxxxxxx",
 "disconnectAfterInSeconds": 86400,
 "refreshAfterInSeconds", 300,
 "policyDocuments": [
  "{ \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\": [ { \"Action\": \"...\", \"Effect\": \"Allow|Deny\", \"Resource\": \"...\" } ] }"
 ]
}
```